# Error updating sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile,      phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing:  osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing:  osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357
```

Comment: update site: http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse - http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

> "If you downloaded ADT as part of the SDK ADT bundle, you may
>   encounter an error when attempting to download the ADT Translation
>   Manager Plugin from the remote repository. In that case, open the
>   Install New Software, uncheck "Contact all update sites during install
>   to find required software" at the bottom and try again"

[reference](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Answer (score 2):

It says that You need to update your `ADT plugins` to latest version before updating your other packages.

Check [Update ADT plug-ins in Android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please give it a try with this repo URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ , it worked for me

Comment: Can you elaborate further, rather than just linking to a resource?

Answer (score 0):

the eclipse version recommended currently is:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplerr

see this page for more information: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup.html#tke_setup.prereqs